# How to grep full words based on partial input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a file `text.txt` which contains the below words.

```
 1. moon,one
 2. sun,two
 3. well,three
 4. doll,four
```

if i `grep` this file using `sun`

```
grep -i sun text.txt
```

I will get the output

```
sun,two
```

But, my requirement is I need to `grep` with the word which is starting with `sun` not exactly sun.

```
grep -i sunlight text.txt
```

Here I need the same output for `grep -i sun text.txt`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You obviously can match `"sunlight"` using the PATTERN `"sun"`, but you cannot match `"sun"` using the PATTERN `"sunlight"`. There may be a language issue with the question, because it seems like it is worded in reverse. The `-i` (`--ignore-case`) option doesn't really apply to your example.

Comment: grep -i sun* text.txt (star)

Comment: @zappy Test your command when you have files named `sun1.txt` and `sun2.txt` in your current directory.

Comment: Do I understand you corrctly, when you want to match `sun` and `sunlight` but not `xsun` ? How about `grep -i "^sun" te[xs]t.txt` ? (The filename changes during your question).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.. yes, you understood my question correctly.i need a command to work on reverse.. Do we have any string comparison method in Linux..

Comment: You can always use your shell to extract the first 3 (or however many characters you wish) from `"sunlight"` and use the substring with `grep`. For example, given `"sunlight"` in a variable, e.g. `srch=sunlight`, if you wanted to match everything containing `sun` with `grep` you could do `grep "${srch:0:3}" filepattern` (if you don't have bash, you can do the same thing with a *command substitution* using the `exec substring...` shell command.

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin.. I will try to use grep "${srch:0:3}" filepattern.

Comment: But,I am having  2 issues in it.. The character is not constant.The file is having more lines... 1) if the word is less than 2 characters, i won't get the output.. 2) if the word matches with two words which has same first three letters, i won't get correct output

Answer (score 2):

You don't need awk or gawk, nor sed. Just do

```
grep -o 'sun.*'
```

Other more complex / elegant solutions may be available depending on the system you are using.

Comment: If you need the `ignore case` option just do `-io` as suggested

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

In your case, it would be

```
grep -i 'sun.*' text.txt
```

Comment: from where that  dot (.) came from

Comment: No quarrel with the answer, but unless the `-w` (`--word-regex`) option is given `"sun"` will match both `"sun"` and `"sunlight"` without the zero or more occurrences of match any character added to the end?

Comment: @zappy - that `dot` is the actual regex form of match any character and the asterisk is to match zero or more occurrences of any character.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin good point, for some reason I interpret the OP wanted the matching lines

Comment: You did better than I did. I gave up interpreting the question. At least you got there.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
awk -F ',' '/^[SsuUnN]/ {print $0}' test.txt
```

or if you want to search the pattern "sun" in general from the input_file, then use this:

```
awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} /sun/ {print $0}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-o`, as showed in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html).

The `-o` make grep return only the matched part. You can also use [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

> grep -io sun text.txt